# How to set on Eclipse to show me all variables i have when i want to use them

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a question.
How to set in Eclipse to show me variables i have.
For example when i write plenty of lines of code and make plenty of variables. I often define variables first, so when i want to use them later in program i forgot sometimes their full name.
I know that in visual studio when i type first few letters of my variables it display's the full name. Is there any way to set this option in Eclipse ?

For example i got two variables: firstArray, firstNumber;

when i write fir = it should display both of these variables above ?

Comment: So you're looking for the autocompletion functionality?  Does it not do this for you automatically?

Comment: It doesnt do it automatically, how can i set it to do it automatically ?

Comment: Usually ctrl+space opens the list.

Comment: @shimonb89 yes, that is it. But i need to do it automatically..

Comment: @MiljanRakita well, then there's an answer in the post given to you above.

Comment: Yes, i saw it. But is there way for Eclipse to do it automatically ?